# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a very simple dictionary with some data on it:

```
some_data= {'totalsForAllResults': {'ga:sessions': '11'}, 'profileInfo': {'internalWebPropertyId': '104132673', 'accountId': '67836206', 'profileName': 'My New Cool Site', 'webPropertyId': 'UA-677293506-1', 'profileId': '108628346', 'tableId': 'ga:108372846'},
```

on my views I have:

```
sessions = some_data['totalsForAllResults']['ga:sessions']
account_id = some_data['profileInfo']['accountId']
property_id = some_data['profileInfo']['internalWebPropertyId']
property_name = some_data['profileInfo']['profileName']
print(sessions,account_id,property_id,property_name)
return render(request, 'ga_app/report.html', {'sessions':sessions},
                                             {'account_id':account_id},
                                             {'property_id':property_id},
                                             {'property_name':property_name},)
```

The variables get printed perfectly on my shell, however django doesn't want to pass them to the templates, I keep getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` but I'm sending variables to the template not a dictionary. Why this happens?

Comment: If the below answer solved your issue mark it as correct, please. It's a good practice to follow in StackOverflow. Best regards!

Comment: Yes, it's just that Stackoverflow was telling me to wait 10 minutes before I could mark it as correct. -- [Look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer)

Comment: Oh! Sorry my friend. Didn't know that!!! Disregard then my previous comment!

Comment: Thanks again, I edit my previous comment with a link with some more info on that! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
return render(request, 'ga_app/report.html', {'sessions':sessions},
                                             {'account_id':account_id},
                                             {'property_id':property_id},
                                             {'property_name':property_name},)
```

to this:

```
return render(request, 'ga_app/report.html', {'sessions': sessions,
                                              'account_id': account_id,
                                              'property_id':property_id,
                                              'property_name':property_name}
)
```

You have to pass one dict as the context. You are passing 4 of them!

Comment: Oh yes!! Thanks!! :D

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!